# I need to add input in List, with button, in Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I want to add some inputs(`newtext`) in List(`list`) with Button(`Enter`), before I typed this code, button on different layout, that was opening this one was working (and I'm sure everything is right) but after I wrote this code (specially 'private fun...") it doesn't work anymore. Can you help me with this?

```
var list = arrayListOf<ListView>()
var newtext = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.Enter)
var Enter = findViewById<Button>(R.id.add)

Enter.setOnClickListener { list.add(newtext) }

private fun <E> ArrayList<E>.add(newtext : View) {
    TODO('not implemented")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not make function `private` in the nested function. 
You can just delete `private` keyword and everything will be good.